# Image upload resize and crop in Grails

Tags: java, grails, image-processing, frameworks

I have a Grails app where user can upload a profile image inside the ../user/create form.

When selecting an image file to be used, the upload should start automatically and a progress bar should show the progress of the upload. 
When the upload is finished the user should be able to scale and crop the image. After that it will be  saved when the user submits the form to create a new user.

Is there a Grails plugin that can handle the requirements? If not, which plugins do I have to combine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For uploading you can use

http://grails.org/Simple+Avatar+Uploader

and for resizing, cropping, scaleing

https://github.com/can3p/iviewer

Answer (score 0):

For the backend image processing, there is a plugin already, it is not in the grails public repository, but it has a repo on github:

https://github.com/ricardojmendez/grails-imagetools

For the frontend there are existing jQuery or MooTools plugins.

Comment: What would you recommend for the upload? I need also IE 8 support and most of the upload plugins do not support that?

Comment: yes but I could not get it run.Do you have an example for that? the Grails documentation for this plugin is very poor.